Is safe to change google-services.json?
I have an inherited app and I would like to enable push notifications, that have a google-services.json  but the debugger it's saying:

Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.

And I don't have access to the https://console.firebase.google.com/ account so I created a new one, and created a project and generated a new google-services.json
is it safe to connect this new google-services.json settings to my app ?

no there's no such issue , you can register your app to account by going to console > settings > general > Your app > provide SHA fingerprints , previously i tried changing the project and adding same application(package ) firebase may warn you that application is already using the another firebase project .

How I can provide SHA fingerprints to my new firebase console app ?
